# Adjusting Stats for Higher Level party

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

Can you give me some examples of how to increase the challenge rating of a basic giant spider to level 5 other than just hp, damage and AC?  What would be your proposed monster set up.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a moment to check out the [tour] and the [help] to get an idea of how things work.

Comment: Are you sure you mean D&D 3.5?  There's no "giant" spider there's "monstrous" spiders and they come in varying size and CR already. http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/monstrousSpider.htm A Huge one is CR5.